# I want to upload excel file with form data including unique ID which is generated from previous request

Tags: file-upload, jmeter

Below is payload of the request and below parameter I have extracted from previous request and pass as expected and I have added file  upfeId":"3EIBAA2","fileYear":2025,"accountId":"RMhn9AAD","subAccountId":"RcEIzAAN"

I have tried to with different configuration auth token and all variable from previous request have been passed successfully but it is showing bad request can any please help to build this request

operations:
{"operationName":"uploadFile","variables":{"Template":{"fileName":"puneet19Dec2022.xlsx","File":[null],"upfeId":"3EIBAA2","fileYear":2025,"accountId":"RMhn9AAD","subAccountId":"RcEIzAAN"}},"query":"mutation uploadFile($Template: TemplateInput) {\n  uploadFile(Template: $Template) {\n    responseCode\n    responseMessage\n    data {\n      list {\n        name\n        notes\n        type\n        startDate\n        dueDate\n        owners {\n          emailId\n          firstName\n          __typename\n        }\n        attachmentName\n        phase\n        rowError\n        __typename\n      }\n      hasError\n      majorErrors\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}"}
map:
{"1":["variables.fileTemplate.File.0"]}
1:
(binary)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can upload your file successfully using browser (or other application) - just record the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html). Just make sure to copy the file you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, this way JMeter will be able to properly intercept the request and generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

All the dynamic parameters could be correlated later on.

If you were just given the request payload it might be a better idea to use [GraphQL HTTP Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-4#GraphQL) which is easier to configure, parameterize and use.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri I am not able to record through Jmeter I am recording through Blazemeter when I am trying to Record Through Jmeter and set my Proxy as localhost and add certificate then internet is not working and application is not opening